# Why does useState hook behave this way?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm building a component which provides the user with multiple counters they can increment or decrement using the useState hooks.

```
 const [counters,setCounters] = useState([0,0,0,0]);
  return (
    counters.map((ele,i) => {
      return (
          <div key={i}>
            <p key='0'>{ele}</p>

            <button key='1' onClick={() => {
            counters[i]++; setCounters(counters);
            }}>+</button>

            <button key='2' onClick={() => {
            var t = [...counters]; t[i]--;
            setCounters(t);
            }}>-</button>

          </div>
      );
    })
  );
```

When I press the '+' button and increment the value of my counters variable and then pass it to setCounters there is no visible change (the value inside the <p> tag doesn't change).  However, when I do the same to a copy of the counters array not only does the operation work, but the result also reflects the number of times I pressed the '+' button i.e the changes that were not reflected when pressing the increment button are now also part of the result.

Also, if I log the value of the counters variable to the console after incrementing it (counters[i]++), then I can see the value has changed, however the value in the p tag is the same.  This leads me to believe that for some reason this component wasn't rendered.  Why does changing the state variable itself cause this to happen?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `counters[i]++;` mutates state. Create a *new* array instead of mutating the existing array.

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes it does.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

On this line, you are trying to **mutate** the `state`, which you shouldn't.

```
counters[i]++;
```

Instead, create a new array and pass it to the `setCounter` method.
Or, even better, pass a function to `setCounter` method, iterate over the array and change only element that you need.

```
const [counters,setCounters] = useState([0,0,0,0]);
return (
  counters.map((ele,i) => {
    return (
      <div key={i}>
        <p key='0'>{ele}</p>

        <button key='1' onClick={() => {
          setCounters((prev) => prev
            .map((counter, index) => index === i ? ++counter: counter));
        }}>+</button>

        <button key='2' onClick={() => {
          var t = [...counters]; t[i]--;
          setCounters(t);
        }}>-</button>

      </div>
    );
  })
);
```